# Resize columns in Div table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, frontend

I am a newbie to front-end web development.
I have implemented table using divs for responsiveness.
Now I am trying to implement resize feature on columns.
Is there any way to detect column borders ?
Is there any library available for the same?
So far I have only found solution or ways which uses HTML table. 
I am using angular js and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use tables. Use multiple div elements and give them a width not in px, but in %. (like width: 25%)

To take the paddings and borders in account, you should also add border-sizing: border-box on the divs. This will calculate the paddings and borders into the 25% width also. Also the div elements also need to have display:inline-block.

Tables don't have these possibilities.